# React passing a variable between two components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components in my React app.
My header component contains a slider. Now i want to trigger an event in my other component when the value of the slider changes.

I tried to use callback functions but i got a error witch said: To many rerenders

Comment: `I tried to use callback functions but i got a error witch said: To many rerenders` Please show the code that you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

Use setState in a parent component. Use state will render all components again when setState is used. If the header and sidebar are both in an index. Then use the setState in the index file. Passing the data into the 2 components.

You can find a whole lot more about this here. https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/responding-to-events